# Data merge with data.table for repeating unique values

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I am trying two merge two columns in data table 'A' with another column in another data table 'B' which is the unique value of a column . I want to merge in such a way that for every unique combination of two variables in data table 'A' , we get all unique values of column in data table 'B' repeated.

I tried merge but it doesn't give me all the values.I also tried the automated recycling function in data.table but this also doesn't give me the result.

Input:
data.table A

X   Y

1   1

1   2

1   3

2   1

3   1

4   4

4   5

5   6

data.table B

Z

1

2

Expected output

X   Y   Z

1   1   1

1   1   2

1   2   1

1   2   2

1   3   1

1   3   2

2   1   1

2   1   2

3   1   1

3   1   2

4   4   1

4   4   2

4   5   1

4   5   2

5   6   1

5   6   2

Comment: pls also see `https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/814`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(A, B)
#   X Y Z
#1  1 1 1
#2  1 1 2
#3  1 2 1
#4  1 2 2
#5  1 3 1
#6  1 3 2
#7  2 1 1
#8  2 1 2
#9  3 1 1
#10 3 1 2
#11 4 4 1
#12 4 4 2
#13 4 5 1
#14 4 5 2
#15 5 6 1
#16 5 6 2
```

---

Or with `merge` from `base R`, but the order will be slightly different

```
merge(A, B)
```

To get the correct order, replace the arguments in reverse and then order the columns

```
merge(B, A)[c(names(A), names(B))]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Arun! But the base R merge gives an error "A non-empty vector of column names for `by` is required" . is this because there are no unique columns?

Comment: @Deb It is because both the data are `data.table`.  Try `setDF(A);
merge(A, B)` should work